# Couldn't save XML file using Server.MapPath

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have a simple asp classic program that update the xml files when a user click a checkbox. It worked fine in my development server but when I deployed it in our main server it display an

> msxml3.dll error '80070005' Access is denied

(the error is in objXMLDoc.Save Server.MapPath(xmlfile)). I've checked the permissions and its identical to my development server.

below is the xml file

```
<notification>
<staff>
    <pin>P001</pin>
    <allow>1</allow>
</staff>
<staff>
    <pin>P002</pin>
    <allow>0</allow>
</staff>
</notification>
```

and the asp classic code for updating the xml

```
if Request.Form("updatebtn") = "Remove in Cc" then

    Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")
    objXMLDoc.async = False
    objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath(xmlfile)

    For Each xmlpin In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("staff")

        pin = xmlpin.selectSingleNode("pin").text
        allow = xmlpin.selectSingleNode("allow").text

        if allow = 1 then

            if Request.Form("chk_" & pin) = "on" then

                Response.Write(pin & "<br/>")

                Set nodeBook = xmlpin.selectSingleNode("allow")
                nodeBook.Text = 0
                objXMLDoc.Save Server.MapPath(xmlfile) ' error when saving the xml 

            end if

        end if

    next

    Response.Redirect("notification.asp")

end if
```

Are there any settings that I've overlooked?

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Permissions are the same, but is the same the account used for IIS?

Comment: It looks like your iusr account may not have permission to use msxml3.dll itself. There's a newer version of msxml now - try Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to check, which user is used by the IIS Application Pool the site is running in (probably IUSR_xy).
2. Make sure, this user has "OVERWRITE" permission in the folder you save the XML file to (in the folder security settings).

I had the issue once, that my application could create a new file, but could not overwrite it for this reason.